# Magento 2: Which tables copy for importing all orders, customers, reviews

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Which tables do I have to copy for importing all orders (incl. invoices ...), customers (incl. guests) and their orders of course, reviews, statistics, logs and so on.

My problem:
I have 2 Magento2 databases. The first database has all products, categories, cms pages, blocks, configurations and so on. But second database has latest orders, but not correct products, categories and so on. The second database has all new orders and so on from data migrations tool from delta mode. But I can not run migration in database 1 again, because to many things where changed. So I only need all orders, customers and so on - all datas which are updated by migrations tool in delta mode.

Answer (score 0):

for orders

```
 sales_order
 sales_order_address
 sales_order_grid
 sales_order_item
 sales_order_item
```

for customers

```
 customer_entity
 customer_entity_datetime
 customer_entity_decimal
 customer_entity_int
 customer_entity_text
 customer_entity_varchart
 customer_form_attribute
```

for reviews

```
review
review_detail
review_entity
review_entity_summary
review_status
review_store
```

Answer (score 0):

**Order tables**

```
gift_message
quote
quote_address
quote_address_item
quote_id_mask
quote_item
quote_item_option
quote_payment
quote_shipping_rate
reporting_orders
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
sales_creditmemo
sales_creditmemo_comment
sales_creditmemo_grid
sales_creditmemo_item
sales_invoice
sales_invoiced_aggregated
sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
sales_invoice_comment
sales_invoice_grid
sales_invoice_item
sales_order
sales_order_address
sales_order_aggregated_created
sales_order_aggregated_updated
sales_order_grid
sales_order_item
sales_order_payment
sales_order_status_history
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item
sales_payment_transaction
sales_refunded_aggregated
sales_refunded_aggregated_order
sales_shipment
sales_shipment_comment
sales_shipment_grid
sales_shipment_item
sales_shipment_track
sales_shipping_aggregated
sales_shipping_aggregated_order
tax_order_aggregated_created
tax_order_aggregated_updated
```

**Customer tables**

```
customer_address_entity
customer_address_entity_datetime
customer_address_entity_decimal
customer_address_entity_int
customer_address_entity_text
customer_address_entity_varchar
customer_entity
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
customer_grid_flat
customer_log
customer_log
customer_visitor
persistent_session
wishlist
wishlist_item
wishlist_item_option
```

**Review tables**

```
review
review_detail
review_entity_summary
review_store
```

**Log tables**

```
report_event
report_viewed_product_index
report_compared_product_index
customer_visitor
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Yassnine's answer is good but missing a few tables. Also needs the sequence tables, one per website. Probably find the _0 (admin) tables are empty so just the tables for each website id required. Below assumes just one website id = 1.

Here's some dump commands that do them in batches:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p [db] customer_address_entity customer_address_entity_datetime customer_address_entity_decimal customer_address_entity_int customer_address_entity_text customer_address_entity_varchar customer_entity customer_entity_datetime customer_entity_decimal customer_entity_int customer_entity_text customer_entity_varchar customer_grid_flat customer_log customer_visitor persistent_session wishlist wishlist_item wishlist_item_option > customers.sql

mysqldump -u [user] -p [db] gift_message quote quote_address quote_address_item quote_id_mask quote_item quote_item_option quote_payment quote_shipping_rate reporting_orders sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly sales_creditmemo sales_creditmemo_comment sales_creditmemo_grid sales_creditmemo_item sales_invoice sales_invoiced_aggregated sales_invoiced_aggregated_order sales_invoice_comment sales_invoice_grid sales_invoice_item sales_order sales_order_address sales_order_aggregated_created sales_order_aggregated_updated sales_order_grid sales_order_item sales_order_payment sales_order_status_history sales_order_tax sales_order_tax_item sales_payment_transaction sales_refunded_aggregated sales_refunded_aggregated_order sales_shipment sales_shipment_comment sales_shipment_grid sales_shipment_item sales_shipment_track sales_shipping_aggregated sales_shipping_aggregated_order tax_order_aggregated_created tax_order_aggregated_updated > orders.sql

mysqldump -u [user] -p [db] sequence_creditmemo_1 sequence_invoice_1 sequence_order_1 sequence_shipment_1 > sequence.sql

mysqldump -u [user] -p [db] review review_detail review_entity_summary review_store > reviews.sql

mysqldump -u [user] -p [db] report_event report_viewed_product_index report_compared_product_index customer_visitor > logs.sql
```

Once dumped, import in the same order.